# Error al crear un certificado SSL con openSSL en Apache Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, certificado-ssl, virtualhost, openssl

estoy tratando de generar un certificado SSL para que el VirtualHost sea https://mi-web.local, tengo creado mi HostVirtual de la siguiente forma, nombre del archivo `mi-web.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mi-web.local
ServerAlias mi-web
DocumentRoot /var/www/mi-web


<Directory /var/www/mi-web>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All

     Order Allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, he logrado ingresar a mi virtualHost, ahora les voy a mostrar los paso a pasos que hice para poder generar los certificados y demás con OpenSSL

dentro de la carpeta `/etc/ssl/` Genero un fichero con claves privadas con el algoritmos RSA ejecutando el siguiente comando `openssl genrsa -out mi-web.key 1024`

Luego genero un CSR

```
openssl req -new -key mi-web.key -out mi-web.csr
```

Ahora el auto firmado

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mi-web.csr -signkey mi-web.key -out mi-web.cert
```

Luego agrego al apache el fichero de claves y del certificado. ingresando nuevamente a `/etc/apache2/sites-avalible/` aquí hago una copia de mi hostVirtual osea de `mi-web.conf` y lo nombro de la siguiente forma `mi-web-ssl.conf` en el tengo la siguiente configuración

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName mi-web.local
    ServerAlias mi-web
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mi-web


    <Directory /var/www/mi-web>
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All

         Order Allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mi-web.key
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/mi-web.cert


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

En este archivo es donde hago referencia de las rutas donde se encuentran la llave y el certificado, como siguiente paso enciendo el modulo SLL `a2enmod ssl` y reinicio el apache

```
service apache2 reload
```

Para terminar en el archivo del VirtualHosts mi-web.conf coloco las siguientes lineas para "Habilitar el HTTPS" fijo del dominio local, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mi-web.local
    ServerAlias mi-web
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mi-web


    <Directory /var/www/mi-web>
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All

         Order Allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond % {SERVER_NAME} =mi-web.local
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>
```

Donde finalmente reinicio mi apache y aquí es donde me muestra el error por consola

```
The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nammu-pay.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

En la linea 22 donde dice que esta el error de sintaxis es esta:

```
RewriteCond % {SERVER_NAME} =mi-web.local
```

Les agradezco a que me ayuden con este inconveniente que estoy presentando, un saludo a todos

> "Espero haber sido claro con lo que quiero hacer y con lo que hice
> desde el comienzo"

Answer (score 1):

por si alguno tiene este mismo problema, encontré algunos errores que y alguno que otro comando me faltaba para poder funcionar mi certificado SSL en local.

Mi primer error fue desde esta linea de comando
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mi-web.csr -signkey mi-web.key -out mi-web.cert`

como ven la salida del certificado no es ese tipo de extension .cert hay que reemplazarla por
`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mi-web.csr -signkey mi-web.key -out mi-web.crt` que quede .CRT.

Luego de corregir este certificado, me voy a mi HostVistual del SSL osea a mi-web-ssl.conf y edito la linea `SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/mi-web.cert`

y la reemplazo por `SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/mi-web.crt` agregando la extension .CRT

Desde aquí había obviado un paso muy importante y era en activar ese virtualhost con el siguiente comando `a2ensite mi-web-ssl.conf` para luego reiniciar el apache `service apache2 reload` por ultimo había que solucionar el error de sintaxis en mi archivo mi-web.conf de HostVirtual pues efectivamente el error era por un espacio que se encontraba en condición `RewriteCond % {SERVER_NAME} =mi-web.local`

Como se ve hay que quitar el espacio que hay entre el % y {SERVER_NAME} para que quede de la siguiente forma toda la linea `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mi-web.local`

Con este proceso pude crear mi certificado ssl y poder "crear una pagina https local".

Muchas gracias!